# JS Игра | У первого игрока всё проверяет, а у второго нет

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр

Я сделал JS игру `Крестики & Нолики`. Я написал логику, чтобы он проверял у первого игрока комбинации. И всё таки, я полностью протестировал, и просто скопировал код для проверки второго игрока. И с ним вообще не получается. Я даже не понимаю, если условия верны, почему он не пишет это через `alert()`, а просто игнорирует? Помогите пожалуйста моей функции `checkWin()`.

```js
var player = 1;
var playerCells = {
    player1: [],
    player2: []
}
var combinations = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [3, 6, 9],
    [1, 5, 9],
    [3, 5, 7]
]
function checkWin() {
    if (player == 1) {
        for (let iOfComb in combinations) {
            let correct = 0;
            for (let indexer of combinations[iOfComb]) {
                if (playerCells.player1.includes(indexer)) {
                    correct++;
                }
            }

            if (correct == 3) {
                alert("Player 1 is win!");
                for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                    document.getElementsByClassName('butn')[i].disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (player == 2) {
        for (let iOfComb in combinations) {
            let correct = 0;
            for (let indexer of combinations[iOfComb]) {
                if (playerCells.player1.includes(indexer)) {
                    correct++;
                }
            }

            if (correct == 3) {
                for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                    document.getElementsByClassName('butn')[i].disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
function setIcon(btn) {
    if (btn.classList.contains('used')) return;
    if (player == 1) {
        btn.innerHTML = "X";
        btn.classList.add('tic');
        playerCells.player1.push(Number(btn.id));
    }
    else {
        btn.innerHTML = "O";
        btn.classList.add('tac');
        playerCells.player2.push(Number(btn.id));
    }

    checkWin();
    player = player == 1 ? 2 : 1;
    btn.classList.add('used');
}
```

Сам код:

```js
var player = 1;
var playerCells = {
    player1: [],
    player2: []
}
var combinations = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [3, 6, 9],
    [1, 5, 9],
    [3, 5, 7]
]
function checkWin() {
    if (player == 1) {
        for (let iOfComb in combinations) {
            let correct = 0;
            for (let indexer of combinations[iOfComb]) {
                if (playerCells.player1.includes(indexer)) {
                    correct++;
                }
            }

            if (correct == 3) {
                alert("Player 1 is win!");
                for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                    document.getElementsByClassName('butn')[i].disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (player == 2) {
        for (let iOfComb in combinations) {
            let correct = 0;
            for (let indexer of combinations[iOfComb]) {
                if (playerCells.player1.includes(indexer)) {
                    correct++;
                }
            }

            if (correct == 3) {
                for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                    document.getElementsByClassName('butn')[i].disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
function setIcon(btn) {
    if (btn.classList.contains('used')) return;
    if (player == 1) {
        btn.innerHTML = "X";
        btn.classList.add('tic');
        playerCells.player1.push(Number(btn.id));
    }
    else {
        btn.innerHTML = "O";
        btn.classList.add('tac');
        playerCells.player2.push(Number(btn.id));
    }

    checkWin();
    player = player == 1 ? 2 : 1;
    btn.classList.add('used');
}
```

```css
.butn {
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    font: 66px bold;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.tic {
    color: red;
}
.tac {
    color: #00b8ff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Крестики & Нолики</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Styles/style.css">
    <script src="/Scripts/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><button id="1" class="butn" onclick="setIcon(this)"></button></td>
                <td><button id="2" class="butn" onclick="setIcon(this)"></button></td>
                <td><button id="3" class="butn" onclick="setIcon(this)"></button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button id="4" class="butn" onclick="setIcon(this)"></button></td>
                <td><button id="5" class="butn" onclick="setIcon(this)"></button></td>
                <td><button id="6" class="butn" onclick="setIcon(this)"></button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button id="7" class="butn" onclick="setIcon(this)"></button></td>
                <td><button id="8" class="butn" onclick="setIcon(this)"></button></td>
                <td><button id="9" class="butn" onclick="setIcon(this)"></button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else if (player == 2) {
    for (let iOfComb in combinations) {
        let correct = 0;
        for (let indexer of combinations[iOfComb]) {
            if (playerCells.player1.includes(indexer)) {
                                  ^
```

Comment: Извиняюсь за невнимательность. Спасибо большое)